# Remove elements from vector as part of string are identical after exchanging position using R

Tags: r

Given a file paths vector as follows, each one's file name containing 3 parts seperated by `_`:

```
file_paths <- c("./test/foo_foo1foo2_2021-01.txt", "./test/foo_foo2foo1_2021-01.txt",
               "./test/bar_bar2bar3_2021-01.txt", "./test/bar_bar3bar4_2021-01.txt",
               "./test/bar_bar3bar2_2021-01.txt")
```

I hope to drop duplicated files when the second parts are identical: ie., we consider `foo1foo2` and `foo2foo1`, `bar2bar3` and `bar3bar2` are duplicated files.

Thus the final expected result will like `file_paths_filtered`:

```
file_paths_filtered <- c("./test/foo_foo1foo2_2021-01.txt", "./test/bar_bar2bar3_2021-01.txt", "./test/bar_bar3bar4_2021-01.txt")
```

How could I acheive that using R? Thanks a lot at advance.

**EDITS:**

```
file_paths <- c('../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke05_2022-01-07.xlsx',
  '../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke09_2022-01-07.xlsx',
  '../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke05coke01_2022-01-07.xlsx')

fp1 <- file_paths
fp2 <- file.path(dirname(fp1), sub("^([^_]*)_([^0-9_]+[0-9]+)([^0-9_]+[0-9]+)_(.*)$", "\\1_\\2_\\3_\\4\\5_\\6", basename(fp1)))
fp1[seq_along(fp1) <= match(fp1, fp2, length(fp1))]
```

Out:

```
[1] "../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke05_2022-01-07.xlsx"
[2] "../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke09_2022-01-07.xlsx"
[3] "../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke05coke01_2022-01-07.xlsx"
```

Test with @Michel Dewar's solution:

```
out2 <- data.frame(file_paths) %>%
  separate(file_paths, c('dir', 'file', 'ext'), sep = '_', remove = FALSE) %>%
  separate(file, c('f1', 'f2'), sep = '(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)') %>%
  mutate(f1_new = pmin(f1, f2), 
         f2 = pmax(f1, f2), f1 = f1_new, f1_new = NULL) %>%
  distinct(f1, f2, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  pull(file_paths)
print(out2)
```

Out:

```
Warning messages:
1: Expected 3 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 3 rows [1, 2, 3]. 
2: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 3 rows [1, 2, 3]. 
> print(out2)
[1] "../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke05_2022-01-07.xlsx"
```

Comment: If you change the structure of the filenames, then you should not expect old answers to work.  There is nothing that will work universally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach using base R only. It uses `sub` to reverse the first and second components of the substring between the underscores, then `match` to identify file paths that are not duplicates (by your definition).

```r
path_unique <- function(path) {
  revpath <- file.path(dirname(path), sub("^(.*)_([^0-9_]+[0-9]+)([^0-9_]+[0-9]+)_([^_]*)$", "\\1_\\3\\2_\\4", basename(path)))
  path[seq_along(path) <= match(path, revpath, length(path))]
}
```

```r
p1 <- c("./test/foo_foo1foo2_2021-01.txt", 
        "./test/foo_foo2foo1_2021-01.txt",
        "./test/bar_bar2bar3_2021-01.txt", 
        "./test/bar_bar3bar4_2021-01.txt",
        "./test/bar_bar3bar2_2021-01.txt")
path_unique(p1)
```

```
[1] "./test/foo_foo1foo2_2021-01.txt"
[2] "./test/bar_bar2bar3_2021-01.txt"
[3] "./test/bar_bar3bar4_2021-01.txt"
```

```r
p2 <- c("../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke05_2022-01-07.xlsx",
        "../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke09_2022-01-07.xlsx",
        "../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke05coke01_2022-01-07.xlsx")
path_unique(p2)
```

```
[1] "../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke05_2022-01-07.xlsx"
[2] "../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke09_2022-01-07.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(file_paths) %>%
  separate(file_paths, c('dir', 'file', 'ext'), sep = '_') %>%
  separate(file, c('f1', 'f2'), sep = '(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)') %>%
  mutate(f1_new = pmin(f1, f2), 
         f2 = pmax(f1, f2), f1 = f1_new, f1_new = NULL) %>%
  unite('file') %>%
  distinct()

 file
1 ./test/foo_foo1_foo2_2021-01.txt
2 ./test/bar_bar2_bar3_2021-01.txt
3 ./test/bar_bar3_bar4_2021-01.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, is it possible doing so without changing original file names?

Comment: @ahbon You really cannot. That is because `foo1foo2` is practically different from `foo2foo1`. Those are teo different files and they are not duplicate. But you want them to be treated as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on @Onyambu's answer that keeps the original file names:

```
library(tidyverse)

file_paths <- c("./test/foo_foo1foo2_2021-01.txt", "./test/foo_foo2foo1_2021-01.txt",
                "./test/bar_bar2bar3_2021-01.txt", "./test/bar_bar3bar4_2021-01.txt",
                "./test/bar_bar3bar2_2021-01.txt")

data.frame(file_paths) %>%
    separate(file_paths, c('dir', 'file', 'ext'), sep = '_', remove = FALSE) %>%
    separate(file, c('f1', 'f2'), sep = '(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)') %>%
    mutate(f1_new = pmin(f1, f2), 
           f2 = pmax(f1, f2), f1 = f1_new, f1_new = NULL) %>%
    distinct(f1, f2, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    pull(file_paths)
```

For your updated example you could use:

```
file_paths2 <- c('../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke05_2022-01-07.xlsx',
                '../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke01coke09_2022-01-07.xlsx',
                '../raw_data/steel/steel_coke_spread_coke05coke01_2022-01-07.xlsx')

data.frame(file_paths2) %>%
    separate(file_paths2, c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'file', 'e'), sep = '_', remove = FALSE) %>%
    separate(file, c('f1', 'f2'), sep = '(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)') %>%
    mutate(f1_new = pmin(f1, f2), 
           f2 = pmax(f1, f2), f1 = f1_new, f1_new = NULL) %>%
    distinct(f1, f2, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    pull(file_paths2)
```

But your updated filenames are very different from your original filenames.  It is impossible to have a method that will work for every conceivable filename structure.  Whether you use regular expressions, or `separate`, or fixed positions, or something else, your final method will have to be tailored to the actual filenames you have.